# Plot a list of tuples into a histogram

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm struggling with the formation of a chart.
I have a list of the following values:

```
[('1', 2434), ('10', 6792), ('11', 5214), ('12', 3354), ('2', 2854), ('3', 5571), ('4', 5602), ('5', 5768), ('6', 7320), ('7', 7341), ('8', 7198), ('9', 6878)]
```

The values range from 1 to 12 for the first value of the tuple, because I'm working with monthly data.

I'm forming a histogram the following way:

```
lists = [('1', 2434), ('10', 6792), ('11', 5214), ('12', 3354), ('2', 2854), ('3', 5571), ('4', 5602), ('5', 5768), ('6', 7320), ('7', 7341), ('8', 7198), ('9', 6878)]
x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples

plt.hist(lists)
plt.title('Monthly Trends in Chicago City')
plt.xlabel('Monthly')
plt.ylabel('Rides')
plt.show()
```

This is the chart the previous code is generating.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: chart image]

Answer (score 2):

```
x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples
x_months=['Jan', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Feb', 'March', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept']

plt.bar(x_months, y, color='b')
plt.xticks(x_months, x_months, rotation='vertical')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This solved it.